# How can I prepare a magazine file for print?

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, creative-cloud

I have some questions about preparing the final magazine file for print.
I'm making a magazine in `InDesign CC` and I need it to make using `ISO coated v2 ECI`. Every picture in magazine before I place it in layout I converted it in Photoshop from RGB to CMYK (`ISO coated v2 ECI`), some pictures are `.jpg` and some are `.psd`.

After exporting as a final PDF, then I use Acrobat Reader to see in Output Preview the total color area coverage - and here starts problems, because almost in every page (there is about 100 pages) its over the limit - over 300%.

What in this situation would be the most appropriate solution to make a final file correct?

Comment: So...  You're using Photoshop instead of InDesign to create this based on the information I read above?

Comment: I use InDesign CC of course to make this magazine. :)

Comment: We have to make sure..  In that case please edit that information in your question because we do get people using Photoshop for print production.  Why..  I don't know but I compare Photoshop for print production on the same level as understanding a black hole.

Comment: I never used Photoshop for print production, only for editing pictures and converting to color profiles. I realy need to understand where is the problem in my magazine project...

Comment: Just a quick heads up… There is a separations preview panel right in InDesign that will do the same as the Output Preview panel in Acrobat. It'll just save you a step when you are checking your ink limits and overprints and such during the output process. Still do your final checks in Acrobat, but it's nice to use this panel when prepping to make your output PDF.

Comment: Ok, but what should I do to fix those pages which ink level is over maximum?

Answer (score 1):

I usually adjust for ink limits at the same time I convert my images to cmyk as part of my colour correcting workflow. I use the Info panel and with one of the read outs to total ink. Then when I am adjusting my colour curves or levels I can watch for total ink coverage.

I also forget to do this a lot, and catch my mistakes in acrobat or InDesign and have to go back and fix this, much like it you are going to have to do.

(There is probably a better way to do this. I'm a bit old school/manual.)

[image]